# Display the master view controller of UISplitViewController in portrait and landscape mode for a specific view

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a hide/unhide feature for the master view controller of my UISplitViewController. So the master view controller should be present in portrait and landscape mode but just for a specific view (the settings). Everywhere else it should appear in landscape only.

In `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` of my MasterController I am writing

```
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate= nil;
appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self;
[appDelegate.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
[appDelegate.splitViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
appDelegate.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
```

The delegate method is also set

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{    
    return NO;
}
```

This approach I found here on stackoverflow really works well, but just as long as I rotate the device. Then the master view controller disappears (and leaves a black space). While rotating it appears and as soon as the rotation is done it disappears again. Further the master view controller disappears complelty if I click outside.

So I implemented the following delegate method to prevent the popover from disappearing

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

That works too, but then the tableView of my detail view is not responding.

If I delete the code from `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and the UIPopoverControllerDelegate method, it works all as expected, but just after I rotate the device.

So my question is, if anyone has an idea how I can solve that problem. The solution should be able to work with iOS 5.0 and newer.

Thanks a lot for your answers!